# Azure Cognitive Search - Semantic Search configuration error

Tags: azure, indexing, azure-cognitive-services, azure-cognitive-search

I'm trying to test the semantic search feature on my index within the cognitive search portal. Previously, I've been able to do this successfully.

When I try to to use semantic search option, I get the following error: "This index must have valid semantic configurations defined before using the 'semanticConfiguration' query parameter. Parameter name: semanticConfiguration"

[see image from portal here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJjYz.png)

Have tried using a few different semantic configurations, but none of them are working:
[configuration image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svxWr.png)

Any ideas for why this is not working would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: check this https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/search/semantic-how-to-query-request.md link

Comment: can you go to the JSON Editor in the portal and confirm that your semantic configurations are showing up after saving?

Comment: @Farzzy-MSFT Thank you - they weren't saving to the JSON Editor, this has resolved my query. :)

Answer (score 2):

I struggled for 1,5 days with this issue before finding a solution.

The root cause is a bug with the Azure Portal. When you use the portal to define a semantic configuration, it may fail to save. Try this by creating a new semantic config in the portal. Then click Refresh. You will get a warning that says "all unsaved changes will be lost". Click yes and you will see that your semantic config is gone. It was never saved.

This is why you get the error that no semantic config exists.

Workaround: You can use the REST API to create the semantic config.

Workaround 2: You can also create a new, simple index with fewer properties with a limited set of datatypes. The failure to save the semantic config is related to certain types of properties in the index definition. When I create a new index with only a Title (string), I can create semantic configs and they successfully save and stay put after a refresh. When I try with my actual index definitions (complex with many types of properties), it always fails.

This is a known bug and Microsoft is working on a fix. I have filed a ticket and I have gotten good support so far.

Comment: Lifesaver, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I got this issue today, and as Dan said, when you try to refresh from the Azure Portal, it says that you have unsaved changes.
Something that worked for me - when in Search Explorer, after 'saving' your semantic configuration, you can press the Save button at the very top of the Search Explorer page, under your index's name. This actually does save your configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on semantic ranker in Azure AI Search
Then select Overview
At the top/middle of the menu horizontally, select search explorer.
Select query options and configure your semantic search.